# RV042 - switch needed

Tags: router, switch

I have a `Cisco RV042 4-port` but unfortunately I ran out of ports and I need to connect 2 more servers to it. I'm planning to get a SOHO switch, but I would like some recommendations before getting one. I was thinking a Dell PowerConnect.

Any ideas will be appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you are looking for a managed or unmanaged switch. Dell PowerConnect offers plenty of features at a reasonable price, but you have to pay extra for a longer warranty. Personally, I tend to be biased towards HP ProCurve they have solutions for every size and budget, but what wins me over is that their products come with a life time warranty. Performance has never been an issue either.

*(They stand by their warranty)*

You can [check prices at Newegg](http://www.newegg.com/Store/BrandSubCategory.aspx?Brand=1186&SubCategory=30&name=Hewlett-Packard-Switches), I imagine you are looking for an 8 port switch.

Comment: ProCurve FTW!!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you need a managed switch, decide whether you need fully-managed (SNMP) or web-managed, and get an 8-port gigabit switch. Move all of the servers to it, with a single connection to a 100Mbit port on the RV042.

I have no particular input on which brands/models to go with - I'd actually recommend checking reviews at Newegg and possibly (less technical) Amazon.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably get by with a cheap 8-port Gigabit switch, any of the ones from D-Link, Linksys or Netgear should be fine and cheap.

If you do want/need managed features then look at the "layer 2" maanged versions from any of those vendors, still fairly cheap.

The ProCurve, Cisco, Juniper, 3com etc. managed switches are almost certainly *far* more then you need (and will cost far more then you can afford as well).